# MapStruct: Change Target of Mapping based on Source contents?

Tags: java, mapstruct, mapper

I'm trying to represent an international address in a class object using MapStruct that maps it from a PDF form.

The address will have a **country**, if this country is America then the address must have a **state**. If the country is not America then the address must have a **province**. I have separate variables for state and province, but want to map something like:

```
@Mapping(target="userCountry", source="Form_User_Country")
@Mapping(target="userState", source="Form_User_State_or_Province")
@Mapping(target="userProvince", source="Form_User_State_or_Province")
```

The state or province of the user is represented by one field in the form, but two separate variables in the DTO.

How can I make it so if **Form_User_Country="USA"**, then the comments of **Form_User_State_or_Province** map to **userState**, but to map the contents to **userProvince** instead if the **Form_User_Country!="USA"**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try some [expressions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions). I haven't tried it, but I think it should be something like this; here, `arg` is the name of the method argument you're converting (so rename that).

```
@Mapping(target="userCountry", source="Form_User_Country")
@Mapping(target="userState", expression="java("USA".equals(arg.getForm_User_Country()) ? arg.getForm_User_State_or_Province() : null)")
@Mapping(target="userProvince", expression="java(!"USA".equals(arg.getForm_User_Country()) ? arg.getForm_User_State_or_Province() : null)")
```